# Appending string to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I'm trying to modify the DIV tag content on server side.

```
string url = "www.mypage.com";
string html = "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='"+url+" title='Submit to Facebook' target='blank'><img src='http://itprism.com/plugins/content/itpsocialbuttons/images/big/facebook.png' alt='Submit to Facebook'></a>" +
"<a href='http://twitter.com/share?text=Atlas Paving &url='" + url + " title='Submit to Twitter' target='blank'><img src='http://itprism.com/plugins/content/itpsocialbuttons/images/big/twitter.png' alt='Submit to Twitter'></a>";

divSocial.InnerHtml = html;
```

When i try to navigate to the appended URL i can see that the URL is not generated correctly. appended url is empty. Whats wrong here

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your closing ' is not correct. It should be closed after the url:

```
string html = "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + url + "' title= ...
```

A good practice to avoid such hard to find errors and to have easier to read code is to use `string.Format`:

```
string html = string.Format("<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={0}' title= ...", url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
string html = "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+url+"' title='Submit to Facebook' target='blank'>
```

instead of:

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='"+url+" title='Submit to Facebook' target='blank'>
```

I think you closed your href attribute a bit too early.